# Spring queue web service for tasks that take about 1 minute

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I need to create a queue system for a web service in Spring boot. The service needs to do something on the server which takes about 1 minute, then the server will respond with a json to the client.

What do I need to use in Spring in order to achieve this is a reliable way?

Answer (score 0):

It would be a good start if you read the documentation about Spring Boot RESTfull API.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: I have made restfull APIs with Spring before, my weakness is managing the queue. I did find about JMS, I think that's what I need use